# compile xcode to the mac osx terminal

Tags: mac, terminal, operating-systems, xcode

Please help me to fix this case.
Check the attached image at this post.

Kind Regards

[image: screenshot]

Comment: & have you done what it says? Manually install the developer tools?

Comment: yes xcode is installed. so i thought i need any command to make both 'friends'. I didn't found anything by the search engine. Tell me what I have to submit, so you are able to promote me a fix.

Comment: I never mentioned Xcode. You need the Developer Tools, which are not dependant on having Xcode installed at all.

Comment: alright, which tool is essential to fix my case?